how to create generic decorator in nestjs
I want to create a decorator to validate my productId in dto class. here is my controller
@Controller('products')
    export class ProductController {
    constructor(private readonly productService: ProductService) {}
    @Get(':productId/details')
    async getProductData(
        @Param() param: GetProductDataParamDto,
        @Req() request: Request 
        @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response,
    
    ): Promise<ProductDataDto> {
// my codes
     }

}

and I created a custom decorator like this:
 @ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'CheckProductId' })
    export class ProductIdValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
        validate(
            value: any,
            validationArguments?: ValidationArguments | undefined
        ): boolean | Promise<boolean> {
            return true;
        }
        defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
            return 'Validation failed'; // Default error message
        }
    }
    export function checkProductId<T extends ValidatorConstraintInterface>(
        validator: new () => T,
        validationOptions?: ValidationOptions
    ) {
        return (object: object, propertyName: string) => {
            registerDecorator({
                name: 'CheckProductId',
                target: object.constructor,
                propertyName,
                options: validationOptions,
                validator: validator
            });
        };
    }

and for my Project1 i extended the ProductIdValidator with override the validate function because this validation will be different for each Project
@ValidatorConstraint()
export class Project1Validator extends ProductIdValidator {
    override validate(
        value: any,
        validationArguments?: ValidationArguments | undefined
    ): boolean | Promise<boolean> {
        const pattern = /^(Y1|XA)[A-Z]*1$/;
        return pattern.test(value);
    }
    override defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments): string {
        return `validation failed for ProductId ${args.value}`;
    }
}

and in my GetProductDataParamDto i used it as follows
 export class GetProductDataParamDto {
                @IsString()
                @IsNotEmpty()
                @checkProductId(Project1Validator)
                productId: string;
            
         
    
       constructor(productId: string) {
                this.productId = productId;
            }
        }



 

and it works but my Problem is how can I in GetProductDataParamDto instead of passing Project1Validator something like this:
export class GetProductDataParamDto<T extends ProductIdValidator> {
        @IsString()
        @IsNotEmpty()
        @checkProductId(T)
        productId: string;
    
        constructor(productId: string) {
            this.productId = productId;
        }
    }

how can I do it. is there any possibilities for it.
Thank you for your support.
